# ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_34 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 25]

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, stanford-nlp, embedding

I am a newbie with lstm, can anyone please explain why I am getting this error?

my lstm model -

def NNStructure():

```
input_text = tf.keras.Input((), dtype = tf.string, name = 'input_text')
initial_input= Embedding(vocab_size, 25, weights= 
[embedding_matrix], input_length=50,trainable=False) (input_text)

lstm = LSTM(32, input_shape=(50,25))(initial_input)  
secondary_input = Input(shape=(50,6))    
merge = concatenate([lstm, secondary_input])(lstm)
first_dense = Dense(128, activation='relu')(merge)
second_dense=Dense(64, activation='relu')(first_dense)
output=Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(second_dense)

model_glove1 = Model(inputs=[initial_input, secondary_input], outputs=output)
return model_glove1
```

model_glove1=NNStructure()
model_glove1.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model_glove1.fit(x=[pad_seq,X_meta_train], y=np.array(Y_train), batch_size=32,epochs=4,verbose=1,validation_split=0.2,shuffle=True)

Comment: Can you add a standalone code to reproduce this error?

Comment: Try replacing the 50 with None or leaving the value out alltogether